# combine data frames of different sizes and replacing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having 2 dataframes of different size. I am looking to join the dataframes and want to replace the Nan values after combining both the dataframes and replacing the the Nan values with lower size dataframe.

**dataframe1**:-

```
            | symbol| value1 | value2 | Occurance |
            |=======|========|========|===========|
2020-07-31  | A     | 193.5  | 186.05 | 3         |
2020-07-17  | A     | 372.5  | 359.55 | 2         |
2020-07-21  | A     | 387.8  | 382.00 | 1         |
```

**dataframe2**:-

```
            | x   | y   | z   | symbol|
            |=====|=====|=====|=======|
2020-10-01  |448.5|453.0|443.8| A     |
```

I tried concatenating and replacing the Nan values with values of dataframe2 value.

I tried df1 =pd.concat([dataframe2,dataframe1],axis=1). The result is given below but i am looking for result as in **result desired**. How can i achieve that desired result.

**Result given**:-

```
          | X     | Y   | Z   | symbol|symbol| value1| value2 | Occurance|
          |====== | ====|=====|=======|======|=======| =======| =========|
2020-07-31|NaN    |NaN  | NaN | NaN   | A    |193.5  | 186.05 | 3        |
2021-05-17| NaN   | NaN | NaN | NaN   | A    |372.5  | 359.55 | 2        |
2021-05-21| NaN   | NaN | NaN | NaN   | A    |387.8  | 382.00 | 1        |
2020-10-01| 448.5 |453.0|443.8| A     |NaN   | NaN   | NaN    | NaN      |
```

**Result Desired**:-

```
            | X     | Y     | Z   | symbol|symbol| value1| value2 | Occurance|
            | ===== | ======| ====| ======| =====|=======|========|==========|
  2020-10-01| 448.5 |453.0  |443.8|   A   | A    |193.5  | 186.05 | 3        |
  2020-10-01| 448.5 |453.0  |443.8|   A   | A    |372.5  | 359.55 | 2        |
  2020-10-01| 448.5 |453.0  |443.8|   A   | A    |387.8  | 382.00 | 1        |
  2020-10-01| 448.5 |453.0  |443.8|   A   |NaN   | NaN   | NaN    | NaN      |
```

Please note the datatime  needs to be same in the **Result Desired**. In short replicating the single line of dataframe2 to NaN values of dataframe1. a solution avoiding For loop would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to sort your dataframe by the index to check how the output would be ?

```
df1.sort_index()
```

Comment: No it didnt work..